# Remove lines from a file that contain lines from another file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file with a list of certain IDs. Each ID is on its own line and there may be some extra text on the same line. I also have a file with a list of confirmed bad IDs that need to be removed from the first file.

I figured I could just run `findstr /v <bad ID> IDs.txt > IDs.txt` for each line of the `BadIDs.txt`. My code is this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ("c:\BadIDs.txt") do findstr /v %%A "c:\IDs.txt" > "c:\IDs.txt"
```

It's giving me an empty file in the end. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double quotes don't let the for loop work correctly, so the file path has to be without those.
2. It's not possible to write to the same file you're reading from, so you have to use a temp file.

The working code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (c:\BadIDs.txt) do (
    findstr /v %%A c:\IDs.txt > c:\IDsTemp.txt
    move /y c:\IDsTemp.txt c:\IDs.txt > nul
)
```